# Make image available from every url, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I wish to put an image in my application.html.erb file so that it appears on every page.
The image is in `public/legend.jpg` and the code in my application.html.erb is:

```
<img src="legend.jpg"/>
```

This code loads the image in my root page, but when i move to a nested url such as:

```
http://localhost:3000/section/32
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
http://localhost:3000/section/legend.jpg
```

I've tried using every king of rails helper but i can't seem to get the image to be available from every url. 
Thanks to all helper!

Edit: 
The photo loads when it is in the public folder, but only in the root url...

Answer (score 2):

Use `image_tag` helper:

```
<%= image_tag 'legend.jpg' %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: place image to `app/assets/images` directory

Answer (score 1):

All the images, you can just put inside assets/images/legend.jpg

Then, u can just use <%= image_tag 'legend.jpg' %> ,then it should be fine.

Comment: also doesn't work. says no image can be found at:
http://localhost:3000/assets/legend.jpg
although the image is in both the assets and the assets/images folders.

Comment: you is what rails version?? you got this public/images/legend.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this,

```
<img src="/assets/legend.jpg"/>
```

For more details read [Asset Pipeline Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: When i put this it doesn't even recognize the photo in the root page. Also tried putting it directly under the assets folder and not in "images"...

Comment: Dont put the Image under /assets. Put it in /assets/images folder. Rails Asset Pipeline takes /assets/images/legend.jpg as /assets/legend.jpg